# How to 'avahi-browse' from a docker container on MacOS?

Tags: docker, bonjour, mdns, avahi

My application needs avahi-browse support from within a docker container. Is there any solution to support avahi-browse within a docker container on MacOS?

[How to 'avahi-browse' from a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646943/how-to-avahi-browse-from-a-docker-container)

The steps in the answer from the link above work on an ubuntu host but do **not** work on my Mac. I assume this is because Mac doesn't use avahi (my crude understanding is that bonjour is used on Mac).

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078097/how-do-i-advertise-and-browse-mdns-from-within-docker-container

Comment: Right, it is a duplicate, but I don't have enough reputation to even comment on that question. Unfortunately this is still unsolved; mDNS is not possible with docker on macOS.